# Delete data corresponding to a particular user in other tables in Parse data browser for Android app

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse as a backend for an android app.What I'm trying to do is to automatically delete data corresponding to a particular user from other tables when that user is deleted from main User table.I am using pointer of user in other tables as a column to identify user.But it isn't working as per what I want to do.Please let me know if anyone here is having knowledge to accomplish this thing.

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to explain what you did and what's not working. Include the code that is not working. On a general note: depending on your data, actual deleting can create tricky situations. A common and safer option is to have a "deleted" property that is included in all queries so that you only show objects that are not deleted.

Comment: @Handsomeguy : thanks for taking interest but I am not using any code.I am just using user interface data browser provided by parse after selecting particular application.What I want is if for example user ABC is deleted from main User table.then its related data should get deleted from other tables.